# AngularI/O & Renderer2: Trigger click event on <input type=file> elmt by clicking a separate button element

Tags: angular

tl;dr: 
**How can I trigger `<input file=type>` in this case without using nativeElement.click?. In better accordance with Renderer2 in other words**

The idea of working with a dom element object in angular4+ component class isn't clear for this use case. This works in the current browser.

Specifically, *this.picInput.nativeElement.click();* But this as I understand it is not recommended (using the element method directly ie. nativeElement.click()). Because it will not work in other platforms.

app.component.html

```
<!-- button element not hidden -->
<div fxFlex="10" style="text-align: center;">
  <a md-raised-button (click)="clickTheInput()">Add Pic</a>
</div>

<!-- input element hidden on the page --> 
<div class="row2ofheader">
  <div fxFlex="10" style="text-align: center;">

    <input #picInput type="file" (change)="alert('changed in input')">

    </div>
  </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('picInput') picInput;

    constructor(private _auth: AuthService, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {}

    alert(input) {
    window.alert(input);
    }

    clickTheInput() {
    this.picInput.nativeElement.click();
    }
```

Comment: HI when click anchor tag you need open file for upload image or  need to call alert funtion ??

Comment: That was just there to test it out. Yes I would have a uploadPic()

Comment: HI can you look at this https://plnkr.co/edit/OpJ2vlGzx8jMMmQIQrnM?p=preview

Comment: looked at it but was looking for a button to trigger input

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables--var-):

> A template reference variable is often a reference to a DOM element
>   within a template.  .... You can refer to a template reference
>   variable anywhere in the template.

So #picInput gives you that reference to `<input>` tag as DOM element  properties and methods within the template.

You might want consider also this:

```
  .....
  <a md-raised-button (click)="picInput.click()">Add Pic</a>

  .....
  <input #picInput type="file" (change)="alert('changed in input')">
```

---

UPDATE

There is an other way to make it sure it works everywhere. Call the same method from both button and input:

**HTML:**

```
  .....
  <a md-raised-button (click)="onChange()">Add Pic</a>

  .....
  <input #picInput type="file" (change)="onChange()">
```

**Typescript**:

```
onChange(){
  console.log("input changed")
}
```

If you need to detect which one of them fired onChange(), pass an argument:

```
  <input #picInput type="file" (change)="onChange($event, 'input')">
```

or if you need to do something after but different from the other:

```
  <input #picInput type="file" (change)="onChange(): somethingElse()">
```

Comment: This works in all platforms? Not understanding the logic how is there a click() method on that variable? Saw a answer similar to this

Comment: Yes, it works on all platforms. #picInput gives you a 'handle' inside the class, using @ViewChild, for example, as you did, but also to reference the <input> element inside the template. I use it quit often as a shortcut

Comment: I upvoted 1 but I am not sure that is the right. Seems like a reference for the Dom Object and the point of Renderer2 is so you don't have to touch the dom. 
*'The Renderer2 class is an abstraction provided by Angular in the form of a service that allows to manipulate elements of your app without having to touch the DOM directly. This is the recommended approach because it then makes it easier to develop apps that can be rendered in environments that don’t have DOM access, like on the server, in a web worker or on native mobile.'*

Comment: Thought I was: Thought they were pretty straightforward. Ie. from the docs page that you linked to. 
*A template reference variable is often a reference to a DOM element within a template.*  This doesn't square with the info regarding Renderer2 above from how I am understanding it.

Comment: It doesn't replace what you can do with Renderer which gives you a vaster possibilities. But as much as you can do #hero.value, #hero.anyproperty, you can do #hero.anyMethod()